# Issue with testing value of properties javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

I am making a battleships game. I have 3 different methods that I am using, the first of which is placeBoat() which is used to run selectPos(), then test if a boat has been placed over another boat. If there is no overlap, it will run buildBoat(), and if there is, it will run placeBoat() again.

SelectPos() chooses a coordinate, and buildBoat() constructs a boat that is three tiles long, as well as making a "hitbox", where boats cannot be placed. If a boat is placed, or a hitbox is placed, the property hasBoat of that tile will be changed to 1, which is how I am checking for overlap.

However, when I run this program, it seems to only place one boat normally, and occasionally it will place 2 or 3, but without a hitbox. If there are any further questions that you have about how the program works, ask in comments below. Here is the code:

```
    var boatGrid = {

    placeBoat : function() { //Runs selectPos() and buildBoat() depending on whether there is an empty tile.
        for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            console.log("boat placed now");
            this.selectPos();
            document.getElementById("boattest").innerHTML = boatPos;
            if (document.getElementById(boatPos).boatHere == 1) {
                this.placeBoat();
                console.log("boat placement failed...");
            }
            else {
                this.buildBoat();               
            }
        }   
    }, 

    selectPos : function() { //chooses coordinates of the boat
            xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
    },

    buildBoat : function() { //constructs the boat
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            xPos = xPos + 1;
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).hasBoat = 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            console.log("placed one tile");
        }
        xPos = xPos - 6;
        for (boatBox = 1; boatBox < 8; boatBox++) { //constructs hitbox
            xPos++;
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).boatHere = 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).innerHTML = "  X";
        }
    },
```

Comment: this.placeBoat() inside of the for loop starts another for loop calls this.placeBoat() again. Thats an endless loop that will crash

Comment: But hopefully, it should chose another position at random due to it calling selectPos() again to verify the if statement. Also, it does not seem to crash when running the program, it just seems to not place another boat.

Comment: Did youve debugged it?

Comment: Why is there a for loop inside of placeBoat?

Comment: The chrome debug said "cannot read .boatHere property of null, so basically, I have a problem defining the object *somewhere*

Comment: It seems that removing the hitbox feature allows me to place 3 boats again, but obviously there is now some overlapping.

Comment: And boatPos is a global variable??

Comment: boatPos is a property, idk whether that means its global or not :/

Comment: Well at least it is accessible in each function and i still dont know what the problem is. However, try to alert(boatPos);alert(document.getElementById(boatPos); inside of the placeBoat function. There must be the error...